# Running into System.MissingMethodException: Method Not Found with PrivateObject

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Basically, some of my tests are succeeding, some are failing. Per Mr. Skeet's excellent suggestion, I created a full code sample to confirm I'm not crazy. This is the code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    using System;

    public class Manager
    {
        private int SampleMethod(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

My test is:

```
namespace UnitTestProject
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestPasses()
        {
            var privateInfo = new PrivateObject(new ClassLibrary.Manager());
            var actual = privateInfo.Invoke("SampleMethod", 1);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestErrorsOut()
        {
            var privateInfo = new PrivateObject(new ClassLibrary.Manager());
            var actual = privateInfo.Invoke("SampleMethod", 0);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestWorksAsWell()
        {
            var privateInfo = new PrivateObject(new ClassLibrary.Manager());
            privateInfo.Invoke("SampleMethod", new object[] { 0 });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAlsoErrorsOut()
        {
            var privateInfo = new PrivateObject(new ClassLibrary.Manager());
            var types = new Type[] { typeof(int) };
            var actual = privateInfo.Invoke("SampleMethod", types, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The first test (TestPasses()) works.

The second test (TestErrorsOut()) fails with the following error:
{"Method 'ClassLibrary.Manager.SampleMethod' not found."}

The baffling thing is the error is consistent, but the actual test is almost identical. It makes no sense. I tried this on VS2012 RC and VS2010, with the same results.

The only thing I can think of is "0" is getting cast as something besides int, which means it can't find the method signature of SampleMethod? I tried a third test to explicitly pass in the type I'm looking for (TestAlsoErrorsOut()), but that also errors out with the same error.

Ideas? Thanks.

**Edit to add**

By using Ian's suggestion of using the obj[] instead of params obj[] overload, it works (test TestWorksAsWell()). And that explains why TestAlsoErrorsOut() fails, because I'm using params method, which wouldn't work with Type[]. So, this is fixed. But, why? Why will params obj[] work when passing a 1, but not a 0?

Comment: Can you show a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem? Is it a typo of 1 for l or something like that?

Comment: Why you want to unit test a private method?

Comment: @Anuraj - I defer to this article on "why", but I don't think this is the forum to discuss that. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9715/How-to-Test-Private-and-Protected-methods-in-NET.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243710.aspx) the arguments are supposed to be passed as an array of objects. Explicitly passing an object array appears to work correctly:

```
var actual = (int)privateInfo.Invoke("SampleMethod", new object[] {0});
```

Passing 0 on its own appears to result in the compiler selecting this overload

```
Invoke(string name = "SampleMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingFlags = Default, object[] args = {object[0]})
```

Comment: In my case I was giving it as var inputObj = new Object[2]; eventhough I was passing just one input parameter.. changing to var inputObj = new Object[1]; solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the System.MissingMethodException when calling the following test:

```
PrivateObject shadow = new PrivateObject(target);    
shadow.Invoke("PrivateMethod", new string[]{"arg1","arg2"});
```

On the target's private method signature

```
private void PrivateMethod(string[] args)
```

I had to add params to the private method signature to resolve the exception as follows:

```
private void PrivateMethod(params string[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ian Gilroy is right, but the reason why; it is because `PrivateObject.Invoke` has many signatures, and one of them is: `Invoke(string name, Type[] types, object[] objects)`.

And in my case, I was passing values like: `Invoke("MethodName", null, null)`, in which case C# compiler prefers the mentioned signature, than `Invoke(string name, params object[] objects)`, which results in error.