# PrivateObject Invoke throwing MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code, in a unit test in Visual Studio 2012.  I am trying to test a private method the `GatherData` method is in the `ExcelFile` class.  However When I run the test I am getting a `MissingMethodException`.  How can I invoke a private method in a class so I can unit test?

```
ExcelFile xFile = new ExcelFile("pathhere");
PrivateObject po = new PrivateObject(xFile);

var retVal = po.Invoke("GatherData");
```

Here is some of the ExcelFile class:

```
public class ExcelFile
{

    private FileInfo excelFileInfo;
    private ExcelWorksheet workSheet;

    private Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public ExcelFile(string path)
    {
        this.excelFileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GatherData(ExcelWorksheet workSheet)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        int endDataRow = workSheet.Dimension.Rows;

        for (int rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= endDataRow; rowNumber++)
        {
            if (ValidateRow(rowNumber))
            {
                string columnOneValue = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                       columnTwoValue = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value.ToString().Trim();

                data.Add(columnOneValue, columnTwoValue);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Its a class I created.

Comment: Can we see the definition?

Comment: added the ExcelFile class to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should not test private methods of classes, but only the public interface, then using any sort of reflection for this purpose, in my opinion, is completely the wrong approach, anyway in .NET there is a system to test protected internal methods with [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx), decorate your under test class with

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestClass")]
```

so you dont break the encapsulation

Answer (score 7):

The method GatherData requires an argument of type ExcelWorksheet in order to work. If you create an object of ExcelWorksheet and then use the code:

```
ExcelFile xFile = new ExcelFile("pathhere");
PrivateObject po = new PrivateObject(xFile);

var retVal = po.Invoke("GatherData", new object[] {excelWorksheetObject});
```

It should work for you.

Check out this post for more details: [Running into System.MissingMethodException: Method Not Found with PrivateObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640793/running-into-system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found-with-privateobject)

Cheers!